# question on string conversion in google scripts

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So i'm basically trying to display this date. But it needs to be displayed as a string so that other functions I wrote can do there job.

```
    let eff_date_display = Utilities.formatDate(oaEff1, "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy");
    let Exp_date_display = Utilities.formatDate(oaExp1, "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy");
    
    
    let stringver_eff = eff_date_display.toString();
    //let stringver_eff = "01/01/2020";
    let stringver_exp = Exp_date_display.toString();
    //let stringver_exp = "02/02/2045";
```

Now I can properly get the dates to display with the current assignments to stringver and stringver_exp.
But interestingly enough it doesn't count as a string.
Now if I go change it to the commented out versions it works perfectly fine.
the code im trying to use it in is

```
'<div class = "input-field col s2"><input disabled class = "oaVerEff" id= "oaVerEff'+i+
'" value='+stringver_eff+'><label class="active tooltip" for="oaVerEff'+i+'">Effective Date<a class="tooltiptext">place holder text</a></label></div>'+
```

Im not sure why it has to be a string I imagine because i'm building these input fields and saving them to a variable and it's a syntax thing(tbh I didn't look into it I just following the documentation). Speaking of which the documentation of the formatdate I got from
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
And ya as you can tell im pretty new but learning a lot as I go

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by get the dates to display, but if you just want a string in the format MM/dd/yyy to display as the value of the input in your example, then you should be able to add double quotes in your html string around the variable like this: `value= " ' + stringver_eff + ' "`

Comment: Have you considered using the built in HTML [date input type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)?

Comment: How are you passing the date objects from Apps Script to client-side?

Comment: @RayGun ty I just didn't have the proper quotations

Comment: @ryansmith no problem

Answer (score 0):

Change `value='+stringver_eff+'` to `value="'+ stringver_eff+'"`